# Method declared on type cannot be called with instance of type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this query:

```
var isTrue = db.Locations.Any(l => l.Position == location.Position && db.Layer.Find(l.LayerId).Name == "MyLayerName");
```

It's throwing the exception

> Method declared on type cannot be called with instance of type

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: This is question is fairly low quality. You have given a bunch of code and with the title of an exception message and asking why. To answer this, you would want to have what you are actually trying to do, why, a minimal representation of the models and schema that is relevant. The actual error, there is usually more information in a exception message. ect ect ect. Trying to ask a question with such a small amount of information is doing nobody any favors, including you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `db` is a `DbContext` and your model has navigation properties try:

```
var isTrue = db.Locations.Any(l => l.Position == location.Position && l.Layer.Name == "MyLayerName");
```

otherwise refactor because ef core cannot generate a query using `Find` and you have to get all locations using `ToList()`:

```
var isTrue = db.Locations.Where(l => l.Position == location.Position).ToList().Any(l => db.Layer.Find(l.LayerId).Name == "MyLayerName");
```

note that this second one will be calling your database n + 1 times.

Comment: Your first suggestion is exactly what I ended up doing but now it's giving me an error that it could not translate the query. It seems it's trying to perform a join but failing.

Comment: sounds like something with your migrations